# What is the equallent operator like "IN" of SQL Server for LUCENE.NET

Tags: lucene.net

How can i get " IN " (of SQL Server) functionality in LUCENE.NET?

Suppose assume that some records are exist with ID : a,b,c,d,e,f,..

So I want to get the records which are in ('a','b','c') by using Lucene.net.

Please let me know how can i write this query in Lucene.net.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a BooleanQuery with the SHOULD clause.

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("ID", "a"), Occur.SHOULD));
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("ID", "b"), Occur.SHOULD));
query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("ID", "c"), Occur.SHOULD));
```

This means that any result must have either ID = a, b, or c.

Answer (score 0):

Query q = new QueryParser("ID", new YourAnalyzer()).Parse("a b c d")   :)